# Ruby on Rails: Replace values in array with hash values (from database model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash, model

I need to replace the values from an array

```
tag_list = ['tag1', tag4, .. tag_n]
```

with the id's of a corresponding database model 'tags'

```
@tags = [{:id => '1', :name => 'tag1'}, {:id => '2', :name => 'tag2' ...}]
```

The desired output of the 'tag_list' should look like

```
tag_list_new=['1','4',..'n']
```

After trying and searching the web, I don't find any solution working for me.

Ps. I am  relatively new to rails and really hope for a working answer, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  tag_list = ['tag1', tag4, .. tag_n]
  @tags = [{:id => '1', :name => 'tag1'}, {:id => '2', :name => 'tag2' ...}]

  tag_list_new = Array.new 
  tag_list.each do |a|
  @tags.each do |tag|
   if tag["name"].eql?(a) 
    tag_list_new << tag["id"]
   end 
  end 
end
```